# Python and PHP / MAMP

Tags: php, python, mysql, mamp

I recently got python working with MAMP in the terminal. The below script works in the terminal and prints what it should:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect (unix_socket = '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
                    host = 'localhost',
                    user = '*****',
                    passwd = '****',
                    db = 'Database')

cur = db.cursor() 

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE")

for row in cur.fetchall() :
    print row[0]
    print row[1]
```

However it will not work when I call it via PHP:

```
exec("python test.py",$output);
echo $output[0]
```

I get the following PHP error

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /test.php on line 7

I created second test python script as the below:

```
import MySQLdb
print 'worked'
```

And it works as expected - but only when I have

```
import MySQLdb
```

commented out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your Python script isn't printing anything out, so `$output` has no `0`th element.

Comment: When i run the second test and comment out `import MySQLdb` the python script will return "worked". It only breaks when I uncomment `import MySQLdb`

Comment: have you installed MySQLdb ?

Comment: Yes, as i mentioned: When I run the python script in the terminal it works perfectly and as expected. Only when I attempt to call it via PHP does it break.

Comment: @Alex: Run `python test.py 2> errors.txt` with PHP and see if you can catch the error into a file. For simplicity, try just running the `import MySQLdb` script.

Comment: write insert or update query and see if that works
also use print_r( $output ) instead of $output[0]

Comment: @Blender like this? `exec("python test2.py 2> errors.txt",$output);`?

Comment: @MySqlError I edited the python script to run an update query. Once again it worked in the terminal but not via PHP. When I ran it in php using the `print_r` I got the below error _Array ( ) 1_

Comment: Actually, after running a couple tests it only looks like its updating it in the terminal. When I run 
`cur.execute("UPDATE USER_MAIN SET EMAIL = 'test'")`
`cur.execute("SELECT * FROM USER_MAIN")`
 it returns test but doesnt actually change it in the database

Comment: My guess is a permission issue for user www-data ( maybe it doesn't have read permission to the MySQLdb package's files. )